# Errors: "[Vue warn]: Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render." and also for "books"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, storyblok

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jY4o.png)I am making an app in Nuxt and vue using storyblok as my CMS. However, I have been receiving errors when trying to link the storyblok array to my arrays called in my template using v-for.

Here is the template:

```
<template>
<div>
<!-- instance header -->
<InstanceHeader title="Books" />

<div class="pageContainer">

<div class="booksInfoPost"> 

    <div class="booksInfoPost__subHeader"><h3>Top Books</h3></div>

    <div class="booksInfoPost__topBooks"> 

     <BooksInfoPostTop 
        v-for="book in books"
        :key ="book.id"
        :bookCover="book.bookCover"
        :title="book.title"
        :author="book.author"
        :content="book.content"
        :id="book.id"
        /> 

    </div> 

    <div class="booksInfoPost__subHeader"><h3>Book Titles</h3></div>

     <BooksInfoPost 
        v-for="book in posts"
        :key ="book.id"
        :bookCover="book.bookCover"
        :title="book.title"
        :author="book.author"
        :content="book.content"
        :id="book.id"
        />  

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
export default  {

components: {
    InstanceHeader,
    BooksInfoPostTop,
    BookTitles,
    BooksInfoPost
},

data() {
    /* return {
        books: [],
        posts: []
    } */

},

async asyncData(context) {

     return {

      bookTitles:  context.app.$storyapi
      .get("cdn/stories", { version: "draft", starts_with: 'books/book-titles'})
      .then(response => {
     console.log(response);
        return  {
            posts: response.data.stories.map(bp => {
                return {
                    id: bp.slug,
                    bookCover: bp.content.bookCover,
                    title: bp.content.title,
                    author: bp.content.author
                    };
            }),
        }   
    }),

    topBooks:  context.app.$storyapi
      .get("cdn/stories", { version: "draft", starts_with: 'books/top-books'})
      .then(response => {
     console.log(response);
        return  {
            books: response.data.stories.map(b => {
                return {
                    id: b.slug,
                    bookCover: b.content.bookCover,
                    title: b.content.title,
                    author: b.content.author
                    };
            }),
        }   
    })


  } 


} 
}
```

I noticed this error more when I tried calling two APIs from storyblok. When I called one API call I did not see this error. I have also tried using Axios but I am getting errors using that method as well. I am not the most experienced developer and If anyone can help I'll appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Your top level object returnin from asyncData has properties : `bookTitles:` and `topBooks: ` so books is not among them

Comment: What do you suppose I can try? I am trying to return multiple API calls at once. If you notice I have "books" and "posts" as objects that return array map that is supposed to link to the array as called in the template of my code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {

  components: {
    InstanceHeader,
    BooksInfoPostTop,
    BookTitles,
    BooksInfoPost
  },

  async asyncData(context) {
    const result = {};
    const mapBooks = b => {
      return {
        id: b.slug,
        bookCover: b.content.bookCover,
        title: b.content.title,
        author: b.content.author
      };
    };

    const { data } = await context.app.$storyapi
      .get("cdn/stories", {
        version: "draft",
        starts_with: 'books/book-titles'
      });

    result.posts = data.stories.map(mapBooks);

    const result = await context.app.$storyapi
      .get("cdn/stories", {
        version: "draft",
        starts_with: 'books/top-books'
      });

    result.books = result.data.stories.map(mapBooks);

    return result; // it has right property names {books:[], posts:[]}
  }
}
```

Well as you mentioned in the comment it was a little mess before. So i tidied it up. The idea is that you need direct property names instead of nested objects. This way it should work, if it is not working check the network tab for the errors.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was guessing that this is what you meant but couldn't visualize the part of returning the objects directly. 

Now, I tried this method and the errors are gone, however, now the arrays from the template (posts and books), do not display in the DOM. Do you know what that could possibly mean? Thanks.